# error: redefinition of ‘struct StructName’ message when compiling in Objective-C on Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, gnustep, redefinition

I'm trying to compile Objective-C code on Ubuntu 12 Linux.

main.m looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CEFoo/CEFoo.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
 {
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSLog (@"hello world");
  [pool drain];
  return 0;
 }
```

In CEFoo.h, I have the definition:

```
struct StructName{  // line 86
 BOOL first; 
 ...
 ...
};

@interface StructName :NSObject  // line 92
BOOL first; // line 93
...
...
@end  // 96
```

When I go to compile with

```
gcc main.m  `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base -o main.bin
```

I get this message:

```
Foo/CEFoo.h:93:1: error: redefinition of ‘struct StructName’
Foo/CEFoo.h:86:8: note: originally defined here
```

I've read this can be caused by either redefining the struct twice, or by recursive import when using include instead of import.

```
grep -r "struct StructName" *
```

Only shows one occurrence of the definition.

I've also searched every include statement in the project, and have found no apparent uses of include vs import, or otherwise dual include/imports of CEFoo.h (the file which contains the structure which is being defined / imported more than once).

How can I further hunt down the cause of this? I assume that I am importing it twice -- if I am, is there a way to watch it via verbose or logs defined for the first time?

Any other ideas what I can do to troubleshoot this?

TIA

Comment: It would help to see more of CEFoo.h, particularly line 93 where the error occurs.

Comment: Also, you may want to add the 'gnustep' tag to your questions in the future, though in this *particular* case, it's probably not relevant.

Comment: @Darren I've edited the code example with lines 86-92. TIA

Comment: I've just added more code to the example -- again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a class means creating a struct for it, among other things. And you happen to have a struct named exactly like your class. For example, check the following code "live" at http://ideone.com/7kvFa

```
#import <objc/objc.h>

struct name {};

@interface name
@end

int
main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the way GCC handles Objective-C objects. GCC (in version 4.2.1 ; I don't know for more recent versions) treats objects as pointers to opaque structures.

When you declare a class named `StructName`, GCC implicitly does the following:

```
struct StructName;
typedef struct StructName StructName;
```

You can see that behavior when you try to initialize a `NSArray` object pointer with a `NSString` object pointer:

```
NSArray *array = @"Hello world";
```

GCC emits the following warning:

```
warning: incompatible Objective-C types initializing ‘struct NSString *’, expected ‘struct NSArray *’
```

So, even if you declared `struct StructName` only once, GCC sees two declarations and fails to compile the file for that reason.

I suggest you rename your structure or use another compiler (e.g. LLVM).

Comment: So it should be legal to have a struct and an object with the same name, and this is just a gcc-specific behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: There is no formal written standard for Objective-C but as far as I know, nothing in the C standard nor in GNUStep or Apple Objective-C documentations prohibit the use of `struct StructName` and `StructName` as two distinct types. So I think, GCC should allow this.